# Calculated row and column percentages for several variables

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
testA   testB   testD   gen
Y   hi  a   M
N   lo  b   F
P   mi  c   M
Y   no  d   F
N   hi  e   M
P   lo  f   F
Y   mi  a   M
N   no  b   F
P   hi  c   M
Y   lo  d   F
N   mi  e   M
P   no  f   F
```

I want the percentages of several variables agents gen. For example  I want testA versus gen and testB V gen. I want to accomplish (simplified) this for a number of variables

```
    row     column              
N 0.3333333     0.5 
Y 0.3333333     0.5     
P 0.3333333     0.5     
hi 0.5          1
mi 0.5          1
lo 0.0          0
no 0.0          0
```

by hand for one part of the table (testA v gen) I have this

```
out.taba=table(test$testA,test$gen)
  cpa=as.data.frame(prop.table(out.tab, 2)[,2]) 
  rpa=as.data.frame(prop.table(out.tab, 1)[,2])
```

This results in the upper part of the desired table, but the output (the response of the variables) are in alphabetic order, ordered as N,P,Y while I want the output as NYP and for the lower part as hi, mi, lo, no rather than hi,lo,mi,no.

Q: how to realize the table, including the preferd order of the responses, without using the hand-operated option?

I hoop someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
df$testA <- factor(df$testA, levels = c("N","Y","P"))
df$testB <- factor(df$testB, levels = c("hi", "mi", "lo", "no"))

l <- lapply(df[ , 1:3], function(x){
  tab <- table(x, df$gen)
  rows <- prop.table(tab, 2)[ , 2]
  cols <- prop.table(tab, 1)[ , 2]
  cbind(rows, cols)
  })

df2 <- do.call(rbind, l)
df2

#         rows cols
# N  0.3333333  0.5
# Y  0.3333333  0.5
# P  0.3333333  0.5
# hi 0.5000000  1.0
# mi 0.5000000  1.0
# lo 0.0000000  0.0
# no 0.0000000  0.0
# a  0.3333333  1.0
# b  0.0000000  0.0
# c  0.3333333  1.0
# d  0.0000000  0.0
# e  0.3333333  1.0
# f  0.0000000  0.0
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Doesn't happen very often though...;)

Comment: Thank you @Henrik, exact as I wanted. I only modified  'lapply(df[ , c(vars)], function(x)….'. I prefer that since the vars. have different positions in the df’s I use.

Comment: Glad to help! I agree with you modification - much better with names of the variables than hard-coded column positions.

Comment: 114 seconds too quick @Ananda Mahto hmmm took me more than 144400 sec, without result, except frustration :)